# No da error pero JFrame sale vacio

Tags: jframe

Al compilar no da error, pero la ventana que sale, esta
    completamente vacia, sin los botones, ni texto.

Sale la ventana pero totalmente en blanco. Si bien es cierto que es algo bastante basico, una apliacion bastante sencilla se me esta haciendo confusa.

Se quiere generar una GUI
que pida `punto inicial(x,y)` y `punto final(x,y)`
para mostrar dibujarla en el panel.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 
import java.awt.Frame; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Color;



public class Grafica extends JFrame implements ActionListener {     

    private JLabel lrec, lxi, lyi, lxf, lyf;    
    private JTextField txi,tyi, txf, tyf;  
    private JButton ba, bc;     
    private Panel pdibujo;
    private Container c;    
    private float xi, yi, xf, yf;   
    private Graphics g;


    public void Grafica(){
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setLayout(null);       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        c=getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        lxi= new JLabel("ingrese x1: ");
        lyi= new JLabel("ingrese y1: ");
        lxf= new JLabel("ingrese x2: ");
        lyf= new JLabel("ingrese y2: ");
        txi= new JTextField(3);
        tyi= new JTextField(3);
        txf= new JTextField(3);
        tyf= new JTextField(3);


        ba= new JButton("GRAFICAR");
        bc= new JButton("C");
        pdibujo= new Panel();

        ba.addActionListener(this);
        bc.addActionListener(this);
        lxi.setBounds(10,0,200,100);
        lyi.setBounds(10,50,200,100);
        lxf.setBounds(10,100,200,100);
        lyf.setBounds(10,150,200,100);


        txi.setBounds(120,25,250,40);
        tyi.setBounds(120,80,250,40);
        txf.setBounds(120,130,250,40);
        tyf.setBounds(140,180,250,40);

        c.add(lrec);
        c.add(lxi); c.add(txi);
        c.add(lyi); c.add(tyi);
        c.add(lxf); c.add(txf);
        c.add(lyf); c.add(tyf);

        c.add(ba);
        c.add(bc);
        c.add(pdibujo);

        ba.setBounds(120,400,100,40);
        bc.setBounds(240,400,100,40);



        JPanel pnlContenido=new JPanel();
        pnlContenido.setLayout(null);
        pnlContenido.add(ba);  
        this.setContentPane(pnlContenido);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }


    /*public void paint(Graphics g){

      g.drawLine((int)0 , (int)this.getHeight()/2, (int)this.getWidth(),(int)this.getHeight()/2);
      g.drawLine((int)this.getWidth()/2 , (int)0, (int)this.getWidth()/2,(int)this.getHeight());
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawLine(((int)(this.getWidth()/2)) , (int)(this.getHeight()/2+yi),(int)(this.getWidth()/2+xf),(int)(this.getHeight()/2+yf)) ;
    }*/


    public  boolean  isLleno(){
        if(!txi.getText().equals("") && !tyi.getText().equals("") && !txf.getText().equals("") && !tyf.getText().equals(""))
        try{ 
            if(Integer.parseInt(txi.getText())!=0 && Integer.parseInt(txf.getText())!=0) return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
                return  false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (ae.getSource().equals(ba)){
            if(isLleno()){

                float xi=yi=xf=yf=0;
                try{
                    xi=Float.parseFloat(txi.getText());
                    yi=Float.parseFloat(tyi.getText());
                    xf=Float.parseFloat(txf.getText());
                    yf=Float.parseFloat(tyf.getText()); 

                    paint(g);          

            } catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
            }
        } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR, llene todos los campos");

        }

        if(ae.getSource().equals(bc)){
            txi.setText("");
            tyi.setText("");
            txf.setText("");
            tyf.setText("");
        }
     }


    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Grafica p = new Grafica();
        p.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tal vez porque estás añadiendo todo a c, pero al final a pnlContenido le estás haciendo add con ba, que solo es un botón, con lo que todo lo que has hecho antes no sirve para nada. No termino de entender todo los set y get content pane que haces

Comment: en realidad no tengo idea, solo sigo los pasos de una guia. importar librerias, declarar JLabel, JTextField, luego mandarlos a un contenedor c. :/

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que empieces con un ejemplo básico, en el que solo metas un botón, por ejemplo, y una vez te funcione, vayas incorporando el resto de controles. Porque yo creo que con tanto setContentPane y setLayout, al final estás pisando una cosa con la siguiente

Comment: ok, probare, gracias.